# How to make text field like this in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I want to make this kind of text field in my application. Could you guys suggest how to create a text field like the ones shown in this picture?

[image: Thsi is text field i want in my application]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're showing in the picture is table view cells, not simply text fields. Do you want table view cells that look like that? You want table view cells if your view controller is a UITableViewController. You can easily create a nib file (cmd-n, iOS User Interface, Empty, name and save it), drag out a Table view cell from the asset library, and then drag in the label and text field (see below) into the cell.

If you don't have a UITableViewController, you could just put a UILabel (for the 'Apple ID' or 'Required' part) in your view controller's view in interface builder and then add a regular text field, write its placeholder in the Attributes Inspector, and then choose the 'Border Style' (again, in the right Utilities panel in Xcode) on the far left, the one that looks like dashed lines (this is 'no border')

Comment: Can table view cell react like text field? I am confuse. @trevorj

Comment: In the picture you posted, there are two text fields (the light-colored parts that say 'example@icloud.com' and 'Required'). The texts that you see in the text fields (i.e. 'example@icloud.com' and 'Required') are coming from the text field's 'Placeholder' property. The other texts (i.e. 'Apple ID' and 'Password') are normal UILabels. The UILabels and text fields are inside table view cells. There are two table view cells--one cell contains one UILabel and one text field.

Comment: Can i do this in different way other than UItableViewController? @trevorj

Comment: Yes, that is what I explained in the second paragraph in my answer. Instead of dragging out a UILabel and UITextField into a table view cell, you can just drag them into the view of your UIViewController. Then you arrange them as you want.

Comment: If you do it that way, you should note that your screen will not look exactly like the one in the picture you posted. To get that (e.g. the gray parts behind 'HOME SHARING' and 'An Apple ID is required to use Home Sharing'), the easiest way is to just use a UITableViewController, set it to use static cells, and set the table view's style to 'Grouped'

Comment: When it's no border it's appear not having text box at all. It doesn't look like what i posted. @trevorj

Comment: Yep. I said why in my last comment here. Like I said, the easiest thing to do is just use a table view controller with static cells and set the table view's style to 'Grouped'. Then you can drag in a UILabel and UITextField from the Asset Library and set the properties of the text field as illustrated in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use UITextBorderStyleLine from UITextBorderStyle enum

ObjC

```
typedef enum {
   UITextBorderStyleNone,
   UITextBorderStyleLine,
   UITextBorderStyleBezel,
   UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect 
} UITextBorderStyle;
```

Swift

```
enum UITextBorderStyle : Int {
    case None
    case Line
    case Bezel
    case RoundedRect
}
```

Edit:

The first image was different from the new one. So, the picture shows that It's a table view(as you can see there's header for each section) that the first section contains two text fields. The two text fields' border style is UITextBorderStyleNone.

Comment: Which mean i have to drag my text field into a swift file right? @Ch0k0I8

Answer (score 0):

Use Eureka! It's an open source library available on Github - https://github.com/EurekaCommunity

It's really useful for creating form-based table views like the one you've described above.